# Pagination in Codeigniter(Cannot show row per page)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had met some problems when doing the pagination in Codeigniter.

It can show the pagination's link below the table

But it cannot show 5 rows per page in each pages, it shown the total rows that retrieve from database in each pages.

For example, what I want is I had total 15 rows data, each pages show 5 rows data.

Hope someone can give me some suggestions. Thank You.

Model

```
public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("order");
    }

    public function fetch_order($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("order");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

Controller & view

```
        $branchCode = "";
        if(!$this->session->userdata('branchcode')){ 
            $branchCode ="ABC";

            //if branchCode == ABC, show all orders from database
            $output = '';
            $pgcode = '';
            $this->load->model('order');
            if($this->input->post('code')){
                $code = $this->input->post('code');
            }

            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/Ordering/OrderListIndex/";
            $config["total_rows"] = $this->order->record_count();
            $config["per_page"] = 5;
            $config["num_links"] = 10;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
            $links["results"] = $this->order->fetch_order($config["per_page"], $page);
            $links["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

            $data = $this->order->SearchCusOrder($code);
            //var_dump($data);          
                    $output .= '
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Order ID</th>
                                        <th width="250px">Name</th>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Pay Option</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                    ';
                    if($data->num_rows() > 0){
                        foreach($data->result() as $row){
                            if($row->status == 'Placed'){
                                $output.= '
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                                                <td>'.$row->cust_name.'</td>
                                                <td>'.$row->order_date.'</td>
                                                <td>'.$row->options.'</td>
                                                <td>'.$row->status.'</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="EditOrderPage/'.$row->id.'">Edit</a>
                                                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="GenerateInvoice/'.$row->id.'">Print Invoice</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                ';
                            }
                        }

                    }

            $output .= '
            </table>
            <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item">'.$links["links"].'</li>
            </ul>
            ';
            echo $output;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add HTML to below created output code and pass the total per pages value.

Codeigniter by default not showing how many rows are display on per page like data tables.

You have to add custom HTML.

Like `<span>Rows per pages 5 </span>`